# Why do I need to build my C++ program using CGAL with CMake?

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, cgal

Beginner trying to understand the whole compliling+linking business. Why can't I build my C++ program using the CGAL library as usual and need to use CMake to build it?

Additional question: can I build using CMake inside an IDE? (For example Code::Blocks?)

@Mike : Well this is what I got from reading [CGAL documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#installation_configuring_using). Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: [This](https://cmake.org/about/) explains, what CMake is. That doesn't answer, why any library author has chosen to use it, but it tells you, what it's good for. CMake is compatible with some IDE's. Code::Blocks is an IDE you should avoid for numerous reasons.

Comment: What makes you believe that you need to use CMake to build a program that links with libCGAL? (Add this information to the body of your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been misled somewhat by the CGAL documentation you refer to.

The CGAL developers have chosen CMake as the build system for the CGAL
source package. It is a popular build system (pre-eminent for cross-platform portability). They also illustrate the
building of their example programs with CMake; naturally enough since
the examples are part of the source package. They also recommend that you use
CMake to build programs of your own that depend on CGAL.

It's fair enough for them to recommend CMake and not suprising that they do.
However: When you want to write a program that depends on any library - `libfoo`
- you proceed on the assumption that `libfoo` is already installed ready for
use in your project. Which means:

- The `libfoo` header files - `foo.h`, whatever - that define the library's
  programming interfaces are on your system somewhere so that your compiler
  can find and read them when you write, e.g. `#include <foo.h>` in your code.
- The `libfoo` binaries - `libfoo.a`, `libfoo.so`, `foo.lib`, `foo.dll`,
  `libfoo.dylib`, as the case may be for your OS - that contain the
  library's implementation are also somewhere on your system so
  that your linker can find them and link them with the object code of your
  program to make a complete executable. (And, in the case of dynamic
  libraries, someplace where the runtime loader can find them).

So, as far as building *your* program is concerned, it doesn't matter at all
how the `libfoo` header files and binaries got to be where they are on your
system, whether put there by CMake or by fairies. It only matters that they're 
there. Then, you can build *your* program with CMake, if you want, or any
other way that you like.

Of course it may be the case when you decide to write your program that
`libfoo` is *not* already installed on your system. In that case, you
install it. Then proceed with your program on the assumption that it is
installed

You need the CGAL library and header files to be installed. That would
normally be achieved, (Linux/OS X), by installing the `libcgal` development package
provided by your OS using its package manager, or (Windows) by downloading
and running the installer. Then you don't need to know or care how CGAL
is built.

If you can't get a development package for some reason or are technically interested
in installing the library "from first principles", then you need to build and
install it from a source package. As the build system for the source package is 
CMake, you'll need to learn how to build and install it with CMake, and do so.

Once CGAL *is* installed, to use in your own projects you only need to take care
of the routine requirements of using a library:-

- You tell the compiler where to find the library's header files, if they're
  not in any of its default include-directories.
- You tell the linker to link the library.
- You tell the linker where to find the libary, if its not in one of its
  default search-directories.

Whether you do that with CMake, Scons, Autotools, a makefile, project 
settings in your IDE or simply running your compiler and linker at the command prompt
with the right options is entirely your own choice. (Although the last is the
most efficiently instructive, when you are a *beginner trying to understand
the whole compiling and linking business*).

The CGAL example programs can be built with Code::Blocks as ordinary
simple projects with library dependencies, as long as you've installed CGAL
beforehand some way.

Comment: Note that for CGAL, cmake will also pass extra flags (`-frounding-math` for gcc) that may be required so the compiler generates correct code, it will also link (and add header paths) with some dependencies (boost, gmp, ...). It will compile examples using an ABI compatible with the one used for the library (matters on platforms where debug binaries are not compatible with release binaries). Indeed all of this can be done by hand, but the whole list of required options is not yet documented by CGAL and is a bit longer than one -I and -l flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the code blocks generator on the command line when you invoke cmake.  It'll create the files you need to use and build with your ide.